# How to store and use algorithms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, algorithm, activerecord, model

- I have a Rails app that displays transportation prices of companies (think e.g. momondo.com).
- Those companies are 'created' using the same data model for all of them. Every company has its unique way to calculate a price.
- I have to implement different algorithms for every single one. In some cases an 'algorithm' could just be a lookup in a table, in other cases it's a math formula.

  So, what kind of data model is the most appropriate here?
  Thanks in advance

Comment: does it really require an algorithm over here?

Comment: sounds like JSON datatype would best fit your needs. [See here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json)

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's a SQL query or a math formula, it would still be ruby code. So I'd suggest putting them in classes (you can afterwards decide if you declare these classes dynamically or not) with, in combination, a [strategy pattern](https://dockyard.com/blog/2013/07/25/design-patterns-strategy-pattern)

Comment: Later on I intend to let the companies enter own algorithms through a web interface. If I store them in classes, they won't stay permanently in this case, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that sounds a lot like yours (different domain). I ended up creating a `Rule` class that has a `rule` attribute that is a jsonb type. Then I created a rules engine (none of the Ruby rules engines fit my needs). So, I just select the appropriate `rule` (in my case, using a combination of `organization` and `name` since my organizations can have multiple rules) and then pass this to my rules engine for evaluation.

Currently, in my application, rules are defined in YAML files, but I'll be creating a front end so that organizations can use the UI to define their various rules.

I realize that's very high level, but hopefully it gives you a directional sense of how another person approached the problem.